# How can I create a complex (ux guidelines provided) tabbed navigation system using strictly angularJS?

Tags: javascript, angularjs, angularjs-directive, angularjs-ng-repeat

## Intro

First off, I'm new to Angular. Second, because I'm new to Angular I can't find the terminology I need to even search for something meaningful that could solve a road block I'm encountering. Lastly, please do not suggest any solutions that use jQuery.

## UX Behavior

So to explain the ux functionality I'm looking to obtain, I've created 3 user stories that you can [view here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/tEqgv.png). To start, when a user opens the app, none of their tab buttons are active and they start at a generic dashboard screen. Once activated, a screen that is directly related to that button is then created. The user then clicks that button to be directed to that screen. If a user clicks another active button while currently viewing a different active button's screen, then they will be switched to that screen (see story 2). If the user clicks that same button while it's current (see story 3), then they will be redirected back to the dashboard. I would have posted the graphic to this question but I have to be level 10 to do that apparently :(

## What I've Got So Far

Based off of what I've seen, it appears the UX behavior I'd like to accomplish could be done using ng-repeat. Since the button is directly related to the screen (branch) it creates, I've placed them in the same array. I'm not sure if what I'm currently doing is even close to being on track with what I want to accomplish using Angular, but I at least wanted to give it a shot. Hopefully the code below is enough to give constructive feedback on.

```js
var app = angular.module('myApp', ['ionic'])
app.controller('BranchCtrl', ['$window', '$scope', '$ionicPopup', '$timeout',
  function($window, $scope, $ionicPopup, $timeout) {

    $scope.branches = [{
      name: '+',
      active: false,
      id: 1,
      current: false
    }, {
      name: '+',
      active: false,
      id: 2,
      current: false
    }, {
      name: '+',
      active: false,
      id: 3,
      current: false
    }];

    $scope.isDashboardActive = true;

    $scope.branchConfirm = function(branch) {

      if (branch.active == false) {
        //User has clicked button and this popup appears
        var confirmPopup = $ionicPopup.confirm({
          title: 'Create Branch?',
          template: '<input placeholder="Name Screen" ng-model="branch.name"></input>'
        });
        //User must now confirm creation or deny it
        confirmPopup.then(function(res) {
          //Create a new branch
          if (res && branch.id) {
            console.debug('New Branch Created for: ' + ' ' + branch.id);
            branch.active = true;
            //$scope.branchActive.push();
            //Don't create the branch
          } else {
            console.debug('You do not want to create a branch for: ' + ' ' + branch.id);
            branch.active = false;
          }
        });
        //User has already created this object and now has different functionality
      } else {

        $scope.isDashboardActive = false;
        $scope.setMaster = function(branch) {
          $scope.selected = branch;
        }

        $scope.isSelected = function(branch) {
          return $scope.selected === branch;
        }
      };
      //End of branchConfirm
    };

  }
]);
```

```css
.branch-menu__item {
  height: 75px;
  width: 33.33%;
  background: lightgrey;
}
.branchActive {
  background: orange;
}
.dashboard {
  height: 500px;
  width: 100%;
  background: #222;
}
.branch {
  height: 500px;
  width: 100%;
  background: lightgrey;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/angular.js/1.4.4/angular.js"></script>
<link href="http://code.ionicframework.com/1.1.0/css/ionic.min.css" rel="stylesheet" />
<script src="http://code.ionicframework.com/1.1.0/js/ionic.bundle.min.js"></script>
<main ng-app="myApp" ng-controller="BranchCtrl">
  <article class="block" ng-show="isDashboardActive">
    <section class="content">
      <div class="dashboard">
        <div class="bar bar-header bar-light">
          <button class="button button-icon icon ion-navicon"></button>
          <h1 class="title">app</h1>
        </div>
      </div>
    </section>
  </article>
  <article class="block" ng-show="!isDashboardActive">
    <section class="content">
      <div class="branch">
        <div ng-repeat="branch in branches">
          <h1>{{branch.name}}</h1>
          <h2>{{branch.id}}</h2>
        </div>
      </div>
    </section>
  </article>
  <article class="block block--menu">
    <section class="content content--menu">
      <div class="branch-menu">
        <button class="button button-light branch-menu__item" ng-repeat="branch in branches" ng-class="{ brancheActive: isSelected(branch) }" ng-click="branchConfirm(branch); setMaster(branch)">
          {{branch.name}}
        </button>
      </div>
    </section>
  </article>
</main>
```

## Conclusion

Again, I've had difficulty being able to describe exactly what I want to accomplish in the "angular" way. And if it so happens that what I've created thus far is far off from the angular way, then please help me understand how I can accomplish the UX goals I outlined above in just angular.

This is my very first stackoverflow question so I hope I was clear and concise. Please let me know if you require more information and need further clarification.

Comment: Welcome to SO! Can't believe this is your first question on SO.

Comment: If these views are preexisting, you could probably leverage the ng-view directive/angular ui-router. You can learn more here [at github](https://github.com/angular-ui/ui-router).